# Flow - Set Apex defined Collection Values in Flow

Tags: apex, api, visual-workflow, external-services

I have used external services to create the apex classes for connection to an external service through api.

The aim is to post value to the external service and I am struggling to set the values for Apex Defined Collection.

I have located the apex variable for the body and can set all values except one, the variable in the body is the type Apex Defined Collection. I need to to be able to set the values for

- qualificationType
- subject
- grade
- weighting

for each item in this collection but have no idea how to do this?

I have tested posting values through postman so have a set of data that will successfuly post using that testing method so can set all other values in this method except for the Qualification which is the Apex Defined Object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Snippet from API

```js
"requestBody": {
    ...
    "qualifications": [
        {
            "qualificationType": "string",
            "subject": "string",
            "grade": "string",
            "weighting": "Essential"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

value to set in flow
[image: flow]

Apex Class for setting variables:

```
public with sharing class qualifications {
@auraenabled
   public string qualificationType;
@auraenabled
   public string subject;
@auraenabled
   public string grade;
@auraenabled
   public string weighting;
    
}
```

Comment: Apex-defined objects are derived from the schema of your external service endpoint. You'll need to create a class in Apex that corresponds to fields in your anon object in the `qualifications` array. A good tutorial is: https://unofficialsf.com/part-1-manipulate-complex-internet-data-in-flow-without-code , the stuff you want is covered in 2nd half of the article.

Comment: Thank you @identigral for the response, I've looked the documentation & I'm non the wiser. 
I'm hoping to be able to add more than one qualification to the apex defined object. I have created the below apex class to set the values in but after setting the values in the flow I am unable to set this against the apex defined collection?
public with sharing class qualifications {
auraenabled
   public string qualificationType;
auraenabled
   public string subject;
auraenabled
   public string grade;
auraenabled
   public string weighting;  
}
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read Part 2? It shows how to use the type when extracting the response from a call to an external service. Rather than replying in comments, please edit your question with details of your flow + your type if you're still stuck.